# wp_enqueue_script does not recognize my js file?

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

my wp_enqueue_script does not seem to work, i can't understand why :

i have a child theme of twenty ten,
i wrote this in my functions.php file  (in my theme) :

```
<?php
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'patScript',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/patScript.js',
        array('jquery')
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
?>
```

then in my header :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/patScript.js'; ?>"></script>
```

and the file is :

```
$(function () {
    alert("hello");
});
```

But alert does not work. The path is correct, when i echo get_stylesheet... it gives me the right path where my file is located. Would you have any idea?

Thanks a lot

---

EDIT :
the console in Firefox tells me that :

```
$(function () {
```

"is not a function" : does it mean it does not recognize jquery?
i added :

```
wp_enqueue_script("jquery");
```

above my previous enqueue script, but same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things-

When you enqueue a script, WordPress inserts the script tag in the call to `wp_head()`, so step one is to remove the script tag from your header.

The second thing is the jQuery supplied with WordPress is in [no conflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) by default, so you should reference the jQuery object with `jQuery` rather than `$`:

```
jQuery(function () {
    alert("hello");
});
```

Comment: great! It such a relief when the thing finally works! :p thanks !